# scrollview not working at all on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Here's the code of usermain.xml
I tried so many combinations of android:layout_height="", the scroll bar symbol appears, but when I try to drag it down, it's not moving at all. How can I make it work? do I need to add something in the manifest or usermain.java?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioclass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Round trip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="One way" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:text="Leaving from"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Going to"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Departure date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dtpicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/Age" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your xml is missing </ScrollView>. Please make sure you post the correct layout xml. Also, post the <activity /> entry from manifest of the activity which uses this layout.

Comment: i specified .java file in the manifest activities and the activity is called just fine...only thing is the scroll bar appears and it just doesn't scrolling down

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `DatePicker` in the layout. `DatePicker` takes the focus and prevents `ScrollView` from scrolling and it might happen that `ScrollView` scrolls and your are unable to scroll and pick values from `DatePicker`.

A better approach would be to add new element like `TextView` and show `DatePicker` inside a popup or a dialog on the click of this element. You can pick data/time and show the picked value in that element.

And, if you want to keep `DatePicker` inside the layout, you will need a custom `ScrollView` which overrides the default behaviour of `ScrollView`  to stop the scrolling if some other `View` wants to capture the touch event like `DatePicker` in your case.

I had a similar use case in one of my past projects and I modified the `ScrollView` as follows

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

/**
 * LockableScrollView can used to stop the
 * scrolling if some other view wants to capture the touch event.
 * 
 */
public class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean scrollable;

    public LockableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        scrollable = true;
    }

    public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        scrollable = true;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return scrollable;
    }

    public void setScrollable(boolean scrollable) {
        this.scrollable = scrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
                if (isScrollable()) { return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent); }
                // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
                return scrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
        // we are not scrollable
        if (!isScrollable())
            return false;
        else
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Next, modify the layout xml to custom `LockableScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.name.to.LockableScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sv_lockable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</your.package.name.to.LockableScrollView>
```

Next, override the `dispatchTouchEvent` method in the `Activity` as follows to stop the scrolling of `LockableScrollView`. It is make the `DatePicker` capture touch events and allow its smooth scrolling.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private LockableScrollView lockableScrollView;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private Rect startRect

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_time_question);
        ...
        lockableScrollView = (LockableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv_lockable);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        final int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
        dataPicker.getGlobalVisibleRect(startRect);
        if (dataPicker.contains(x, y)) {
            lockableScrollView.setScrollable(false);
        } else {
            lockableScrollView.setScrollable(true);
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
}
```

I have tried to explain as much as I could while trying to not write a long answer. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioclass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Round trip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="One way" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Leaving from"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Going to"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Departure date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dtpicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/Age" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close ScrollView at end .. just close it ..

java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // activity_main your xml layout
// now i test on device its work perfectly , comment your other functionality and test it 
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioclass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Round trip" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="One way" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Leaving from"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Going to"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Departure date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dtpicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Age"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: edit answer now check it.. 
create activity and than just attach only xml layout .. than check it

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, Try this code.May it help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioclass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Round trip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="One way" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:text="Leaving from"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Going to"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Departure date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dtpicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/Age" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Class"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> If not work fine in your case then let me know.

Comment: please tell me your problem in detail.